# I need to do a Webservice POST request passing as parameter a json file for Objective-C using AFNetworking Library

Tags: objective-c, json, post, parameters

I have created a simple request to get a token from an url. I need to pass as a parameter a json, but I am getting an error while trying to connect. I just simulate the same process i do with POSTMAN, but I cannot get the token back.

```
-(void)getTOKEN:(NSString*)url Body:(NSDictionary*)body{

 AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

NSDictionary *header=@{@"Content-Type":@"application/json; charset=utf-8"};

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"\"UserId\"", @"\"User1\"", @"\"Password\"", @"\"test\"",@"\"isCuit\"",@"false", nil];

[manager POST:url parameters:params headers:header progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
      NSLog(@"JSON: %@", responseObject);
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                           postNotificationName:@"getToken"
                                 object:self];
} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
         NSLog(@"Error: %@", error.description);
    self->Token=error.description;
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
                       postNotificationName:@"getToken"
                             object:self];
   }];


}
```

The json parameter is as simple as:

```
{
   "UserId":"user1",
   "Password":"test",
   "isCuit":"false" 
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set., NSUnderlyingError=0x283ee9d40 {Error Domain=com.alamofire.error.serialization.response Code=-1011 "Request failed: internal server error (500)" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Request failed: internal server error (500), NSErrorFailingURLKey=XXXX com.alamofire.serialization.response.error.data={length = 275, bytes = 0x22546865 20696e63 6f6d696